# Moving to the UK & being self employed?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, brexit, self-employment

Could I, as an international, move to the UK and start working there self-employed, as a freelancer in the IT sector, for example? Or even start a company in the IT sector, with a few employees?

My wife is from the UK, I myself am not, but I am self-employed in the country we're in right now. We're thinking of moving to the UK, but I would want to continue my work as is, and continue being self-employed. How would this work, do you think?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say that your wife if 'from the UK', do you mean that she holds UK citizenship?

Comment: Do you live in another EU country at the moment?

Comment: @ouflak yes, she holds UK citizenship, that's what I meant.

Comment: @phoog I do, I hold German citizenship. But Brexit would not guarantee me that EU laws will stay the same, I suppose?

Comment: @J.Miller EU rules still apply; nobody knows precisely what will happen with Brexit. As a German citizen, you are all set.  In the post-Brexit world, youmay retain some advantage and you may not, not if you move before Brexit, you probably will.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no problem with being self employed once you have the right to work in the UK. Most likely you would get a family visa, unless you have the means to obtain an investor visa. You tagged the question with brexit but that won't affect you directly unless you're an EU national (edit: or you are living in another EU country with your spouse now)(I have assumed you are not). Here's the family visa link. You and your spouse will need to meet some financial requirements to qualify. https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa

Comment: Brexit would be significant if they now live in another EU country.